# python int object is not callable?

Tags: python, list

Relatively new to `Python`. 
I'm trying to practice linked list but I'm stuck with an *error* and couldn't figure out what the issue is.

The error:

```
    self.assertEqual(l.size(), 1)
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

The code:

```
from node import Node

class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, item):
        temp = Node(item)
        temp.setNext(self.head)    # ERROR ON THIS LINE
        self.head = temp
        size += 1

    def size(self):
        return self.size

    ...
```

Node:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    ....
```

Test:

```
import unittest
import unorderedlist

class TestUnorderedList(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_add(self):
        l = unorderedlist.List()
        l.add(8)
        self.assertEqual(l.size(), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

It's funny because if I rename the `size()` to len and call it like `l.len()` it works fine. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: I'd suggest `self._size` for the data; that way you're not stomping on the method.

Comment: Is `self.size` a method or data?

Comment: @PeterWood, ...well, that's the problem; in the code here, it's both at different times.

Comment: But it's your code. Change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the line `self.size = 0` you hide the methode `size`, so `size` is an int and not a method anymore.

Comment: I've typically seen the term "shadow" as opposed to "hide".

Answer (score 0):

You have hidden your method with the attribute. 
In your code you are then accessing the attribute which is of type `int` and so not callable.
Avoid to name methods and attributes the same.

In case you want to achieve properties. There is the `@property` decorator:

```
@property
def size(self):
    return self._size
```

In your constructor you just define `self._size` and work internally with it.